# BX Slider Thumbnail Pager & WordPress Loop

Tags: wordpress, thumbnails, pager, bxslider

I'm having difficulty configuring the BX Slider pager thumbnail slider in WordPress loop.  Here's what I have set up:

```
<?php       
global $post;
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
'category_name' => 'BX',
'numberposts' => '-1',
'order' => 'ASC'
);
$services_posts = get_posts($args);
?>

<div class="span8">

  <ul class="bxslider">

   <?php $count=0;foreach($services_posts as $post) : setup_postdata($post);$count++; ?>
   <?php $bx_large = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'bx-large'); ?>

        <li id="slider-<?php echo $count; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $bx_large[0]; ?>" height="<?php echo $bx_large[2]; ?>" width="<?php echo $bx_large[1]; ?>" alt="Image"></li>

   <?php endforeach; ?>

  </ul>

</div>

<div class="span4">

 <div id="bx-pager">

      <div class="row-fluid">

        <?php $count=0;foreach($services_posts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); $count++; ?>
        <?php $bx_small = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'bx-small'); ?>

        <a data-slide-index="" href="#slider-<?php echo $count; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $bx_small[0]; ?>" height="<?php echo $bx_small[2]; ?>" width="<?php echo $bx_small[1]; ?>" alt="Image"></a>

        <?php endforeach; ?>

    </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

This Slides once then no more.  It seems it comes down to the:

```
data-slide-index
```

Not sure what do with that.  I tried adding the $count to it, but it didn't work.  Kind of at a loss which way to go with it.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I always have trouble trying to read PHP in the html. Usually when I am in your position, I do the following

- Load the page in a browser
- View the page source ("ctrl + u" in Firefox and Chrome)
- Looking at the page source, try and identify any problems in the html that was rendered

In your codes, I did notice that your img tag is closed using only a:

```
 >
```

What happens if you close your image with a

```
/>
```

instead?

Answer (score 0):

You just put the  $count++; at the end of your li so it will count from 0 onwards. Your code is working no need to change it.

```
    <li><img src="<?php echo $bx_large[0]; ?>" height="<?php echo $bx_large[2]; ?>" width="<?php echo $bx_large[1]; ?>" alt="Image"></li>
```